# How can I compound a if and for loop inside a print statement in Python

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to combine this into one line -

```
for x in set(l_rooms): 
    if l_rooms.count(x) == 1: 
         print(x)
```

I tried:

```
print(x for x in set(l_rooms) if l_rooms.count(x)== 1)
```

but that only yields a generator object and doesn't actually print

Comment: Add list brackets around the generator; that forces a list comprehension to make the collection.

Comment: Why do you _want_ to turn this into a one-liner? And what output do you want? If you want the same output as the original separate `print` statements, with each value printed as its `str` on its own line, instead of each value printed as its `repr` (with quotes, any special characters escaped, etc.) between commas in a big list display, you'd have to do something like `print(*(x for x in set(l_rooms) if l_rooms.count(x)==1), sep='\n')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print([x for x in set(l_rooms) if l_rooms.count(x)==1])
```